# Minimizing the number of machine starts

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, scheduling

Please, if somebody has another approach to a similar MIP problem...

Assume we have some machines $m$ and their activity could be interpreted by the boolean decision variable $x_{i,j} \ i \in m, j \in n$, where $m$ is `the number of machines` and $n$ is `a number of equal time intervals`. The objective is to minimize the number of machine starts on all intervals: for every machine $i \in \{1,\cdots,m\}$ and for all time intervals $j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ minimize cases when $x[i,j]= 0$ and in the $x[i,j+1]= 1$.

To do this I'm using an idea to maximize the number of cases when $x[i,j] = x[i,j+1]$ or by adding and minimizing the additional boolean variable $s$ (relay previous equation to $x[i,j]+p[i,j+1]=x[i,j+1]+s[i,j+1]$ and remove $p$):

$$\begin{aligned} \text { minimize } & \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=2}^{n} s_{i,j}\\ 
\text { s.t: } \quad & x_{i,j+1} - x_{i,j} \leq s_{i,j+1}\\
&\forall i \in 1,\cdots,m\\
&\forall j \in 1,\cdots,n-1\\
\end{aligned}$$

The real number of machines is about $200$ and the number of time intervals is also about $200$. The model also has some `material balancing` part-total amount of variables in the model is about $500K$ and a little bit less constraints. It is step by step solving process with different objectives. For every other objective, it solves fine in $1$ or $2$ minutes, but for the objective $1$ mentioned above, the search process is nether ended. Only switching to `solution polishing` helps to find new solutions, but it's not optimal enough and the solving time is not acceptable at all. The problem of $50$ machines and $200$ time intervals is working fine.

Please, could you help if any other formulation could be used? or maybe some `symmetry breaking` constraint? MIP is not good for this?

Comment: Recognizing symmetries would involve the unspecified remainder of the model (the "material balancing" part etc.); there is no inherent symmetry in just the "machine switching on" part.

Comment: Depending on what the rest of the problem looks like, you might -- or might not -- have better luck with a constraint programming (CP) model.

Comment: Could you more elaborate on clarifying the problem? Do these machines process the activities in the parallel form (I mean, have you faced by parallel machine scheduling problem)? Or there is another limitation? What exactly do you mean by the number of machine starts? Are you trying to solve a multi-objective optimization problem or the problem is the kind of lot size modeling?